# assert no database update attempts during django pytest

Tags: database, django-models, pytest

I'm writing a django test and I want to assert that no update attempts have been made to the database, but I don't want to mock the models because I'm still using them to read information from the database.

Is there any way to assert that no update attempts have happened in the database? Or, more specifically, is there a way to assert that no new update attempts have happened in a particular table or particular row?

Typically I could query the DB after the function to see if a value has been updated, but I want to guard against even attempted updates. For instance, I want to guard against code calling `User.objects.update(age=new_age)` when it should know that `user.age` already is equal to `new_age`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can capture queries during a test with `django.test.utils.CaptureQueriesContext`

Example:

```py
from django.db import connection
from django.test.utils import CaptureQueriesContext

def test_no_db_updates():
    with CaptureQueriesContext(connection) as context:
        do_test()

    for query in context.captured_queries:
        sql = query['sql']
        assert not (sql.startswith('INSERT INTO ') or sql.startswith('UPDATE ')), \
            'The DB was unexpectedly updated:\n' + sql
```

If you want to check for a specific table, assert it doesn't start with

`` f'INSERT INTO `{TheModel._meta.db_table}`' ``

or

`` f'UPDATE `{TheModel._meta.db_table}`' ``